# Viewing if statements results

Tags: c#, debugging, if-statement, helper

I am creating the AI for my Turn Based Strategy game and the idea is there are tiles like in Chess and those **tiles** can contain units.

In my class I keep a list of enemy units and want to sort them based on their "**Threat level**".

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enemy unit
    /// </summary>
    public Unit Unit { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Distance towards other side of the board / victory
    /// </summary>
    public float Distance { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Allied Unit covering the lane
    /// </summary>
    public Unit CoveringUnit { get; set; }
```

However I am struggling a little bit with my if statement:

```
 public int CompareTo(AiEnemyUnit pOther)
    {
        if (CoveringUnit == null && pOther.CoveringUnit == null)
            return Distance.CompareTo(pOther.Distance);
        if (CoveringUnit != null && pOther.CoveringUnit == null)
            return 1;
        if (CoveringUnit == null && pOther.CoveringUnit != null)
            return -1;
        // coverunits are both not null
        Unit lvWinningUnit = GameManager.Instance.WhoWouldWin(this.Unit, this.CoveringUnit);
        Unit lvWinningOtherUnit = GameManager.Instance.WhoWouldWin(pOther.Unit, pOther.CoveringUnit);
        if ((lvWinningUnit == null && lvWinningOtherUnit == null) ||
            lvWinningUnit == this.Unit && lvWinningOtherUnit == pOther.Unit)
            return Distance.CompareTo(pOther.Distance);
        if (lvWinningUnit == this.CoveringUnit && lvWinningOtherUnit != pOther.CoveringUnit)
            return -1;
        if (lvWinningUnit != this.CoveringUnit && lvWinningOtherUnit == pOther.CoveringUnit)
            return 1;
        Debug.Log("CompareTo AiEnemyUnit couldn't compare??");
        return Distance.CompareTo(pOther.Distance);
    }
```

The **CoveringUnit** is the unit ( ought to be a list, but w.e. ) that is already covering the lane the enemy unit is in, so if **this object** has a **CoverUnit** and the **Other object** doesn't then the **Other** object should have priority, since it needs to spawn a unit to Cover that lane.

It keeps giving me Debug message, but I cannot debug this with Unity.

So my question is:

Is there a tool or online website for helping with if statements to see what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1:  Rephrase suggested by @paqogomez:

What is am I missing in my CompareTo function?

Comment: What is the Debug message?  Additionally, asking for a tool or offsite resource is off topic for SO.  Please rephrase your question to direct it more toward how to fix your dilemma.

Comment: @paqogomez like Grant Winney said, it is indeed the second last line of my code. And I don't mind rephrasing my question, but that would basically be me asking to fix my CompareTo method because I am too dense to be able to do it myself, plus the tool or offsite resource would be useful in the future.

Comment: Why can't you debug it? Both Mono and VisualStudio are able to debug your c# code although for VS you need plugin (http://unityvs.com/)

Comment: I did install UnityVs it works on my laptop, but doesn't work on my home pc for some reason. I'll try reinstalling see if that helps.

Comment: apply horror debugger principle: Debug.Log after every line of code and print out objects/values used in ifs. as in aradil's answer.

Comment: @grapkulec As I've put in my answer, that's literally the only thing you can do without a debugger. But you don't have to put them after every line, just analyze the control flow of your application and print out the variables that matter.

Comment: @aradil - well, you don't have to put them after every line but sometimes this is how it ends, hence: horror debugger :)

Comment: Are all the null check covered properly, For instance can pOther be null? There is no check for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Visual Studio debugging working again by reinstalling UnityVS.

```
if ((lvWinningUnit == null && lvWinningOtherUnit == null) ||
                lvWinningUnit == this.Unit && lvWinningOtherUnit == pOther.Unit ||
                lvWinningUnit == this.CoveringUnit && lvWinningOtherUnit == pOther.CoveringUnit)
```

Had to add:  **|| lvWinningUnit == this.CoveringUnit && lvWinningOtherUnit == pOther.CoveringUnit)**

Found it :)

Answer (score 2):

Without having a proper IDE that supports debugging, you're going to have to do it exactly the way you've already started doing it.

In your debug message, print out some of the variables you've used in the if statements above to determine their actual values.

```
Debug.Log("CoveringUnit Won: " + lvWinningUnit == this.CoveringUnit)
Debug.Log("Other CoveringUnit Won: " + lvWinningOtherUnit == pOther.CoveringUnit)
```

You're going to find that both of those return false or both of them return true, otherwise you wouldn't be hitting your debug message at all.

I'm guessing you have a bug in the logic of your WhoWouldWin method. I'm not certain if you should be comparing a Unit to a CoveringUnit either, because I don't entirely understand your domain.